Closing reasons and the limited available migration target sites
I came across this question: Determine the engine power
This is a perfectly fine question (maybe, unless it is homework, but it is still a good example of this!), just not for this particular site. When voting to close, there is an option of "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" when selecting community specific reason, but it doesn't give you anywhere to vote on which site it would be better suited to. My only options were meta and super user, when it would clearly be suited more to Engineering.
Is there a way we can let people select which SE would be better suited, or was there a reason this isn't allowed?

SE would rather have mods do migrations, because they can make sure the prerequisites are met for migration. Just flag the question and a mod will take care of it.

MCG (and all) - FYI here are a couple of links to some similar meta question (also check the "Related" list on the right side of this page) for those who want to see previous discussions: "Can we add the option to migrate questions to DIY?" and "Would it be a good idea to have more "this question belongs on another site" options?" || Also, for 10k users, our site's migration stats for the last 90 days, can be seen here.


Is there a way we can let people select which SE would be better suited, or was there a reason this isn't allowed?

Fair question :)
It's Stack Exchange who decide on that list of migration targets for each site. I remember from a previous attempt when we requested to add other sites to that list, the request was refused by SE as we didn't have enough posts going to the other sites we wanted to add to that list.
On that basis, it seems unlikely that SE would add Engineering.SE to our list of migration targets, as the number of questions we get which could be migrated to there, seems small.
It's worth looking at this old 2010 blog post "New Question Migration Paths" for some more context, as that seems to confirm the refusal reason we were given before, when requesting to add more target sites to the list:

Now, we are only "unlocking" migration paths that have some history of actually happening on the site. In other words, the odds of a bicycles or cooking question being accidentally asked on Stack Overflow is so vanishingly slim that we don't need to put it in the dialog or even allow it to happen at all.
...

The default is plain, no migration off-topic. That's by design. If there is ever any doubt in your mind about where a question belongs, the safest option is to vote it off-topic and let it remain on the site. Please don't vote for a migration unless you feel strongly about it.
...
We don't want too many choices in the off-topic dialog. There's a practical maximum limit of about six target sites -- ideally less. Every time we present that off-topic dialog we are asking our community members to think about where this question belongs, and having too many choices leads to analysis paralysis. There should be a few clear migration targets, and beyond that ... flag it for moderator attention if it's so doggone exceptional!


As mentioned there, people can flag a question for a mod to consider migrating. Mods can migrate to any site - but then it has our reputation attached to the migration, so we want to get it right. Don't be offended if we don't migrate in response to a flag.
A question should be exceptionally deserving of migration, and clearly of high-quality, before someone flags it for a mod to migrate. And since flagging for mod attention bypasses the usual need for several (currently 3) votes to migrate, we don't know if any other site members would agree with the one person who is flagging for a mod to do the migration. So we have to use our own judgement.
Some sites push back on migrations to their site, so based on experience of responses from other sites, I have my own policies of which sites I would consider migrating to, and just how confident I have to be that the question will be well-received, before doing that.
I don't know the policies, procedures and etiquette of every other site. As an example, I don't mind admitting that my success rate for migrating questions to Stack Overflow is 0% - all of the questions I have migrated to SO got closed there and bounced back to here. So clearly I'm not a good judge of what is allowed on SO, which is not a complete surprise, as I don't hang out there much. The point is: Successful (and appreciated) migration depends on knowing the target site well, see below.
One more issue is that after migration, some OPs never engage with the migrated question on the new site. That leads to frustration on the target site towards the OP (for not answering follow-up questions) and towards us (for doing a migration which has wasted the time of site members over there). Sometimes I have insisted that before migration, an OP confirms that they really want the question migrated (not all of them do!) and that they create an account at the target site first (so they can immediately receive any comments from the target site in their notification inbox). That process makes it much less likely that the migrated question will be dead-on-arrival and those questions seem more successful. But the admin overhead of all that communication means I don't always have time to do it.
That leads on to the issue that, unless someone does know the policies and etiquette for a target site, how will they be able to judge whether a question will be acceptable there?
As it says in the Migration Workflow:

Be familiar with the destination site. If you are not familiar with the destination site, read through its about page and help center thoroughly and make sure the question actually belongs there. Don't just look at the name of a site and automatically assume that the question can be asked there. Each site has its own rules, and rules vary greatly across sites.

and

If you're not sure, don't vote to migrate it. Let someone else who is sure do that, just vote to close it normally, or ask for opinions from the community in a relevant chat room.

You also said:

This is a perfectly fine question (maybe, unless it is homework, but it is still a good example of this!)

To me, there are factors which do make it appear to be a homework-type question, with no attempt at a solution. For that reason, I won't be volunteering to migrate it, since only high-quality questions should be considered for migration.

One more point about migration which some people misunderstand, so I'll add it here:
While it's nice to consider migration, migrating a question is a courtesy, not a requirement (and can never be demanded e.g. by an OP). The purpose of migration, if done properly, is to help an OP (if we are sure we've identified a more appropriate site, where the question would be accepted in its current state) and to help the target site (by sending traffic their way and giving them an opportunity to receive a good-quality question). However unless we are sure the migration will be helping both parties, closing a question here due to it being off-topic is also OK (especially if someone gives the OP polite advice about a more appropriate SE site or for how to improve the question before asking it elsewhere).

Answered this very well. I hadn't really considered the other side of the migration to be honest. But you would think that there are a number of sites that we would be likely to have certain questions better placed. Engineering, Arduino, Home improvement and SO are ones that are more likely to have people unsure where to post. But I agree with limiting the choices as we are very unlikely to get questions about say... Bicycles. I do think this question in the example isn't a candidate for a good question, but it was really a point to show that it is very clearly engineering rather than EE

MCG - Hi, Yes, you would have thought we could have a pre-populated list of sites that we were likely to possibly want to migrate to. But SE said no, we need to show the justification first (by doing plenty of migrations to that site) before it would be considered for adding to the standard list of target sites. || Agreed about the specific question that you mentioned, it's a good example of an engineering question rather than EE question. || Other mods might take a different view about migrating that question, as my judgement is based on my experiences (good & bad)...
